# Why locals and autos window in Visual Studio 2012 empty?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple program which I want to see in debug mode, but when I start it in debug mode my locals and autos are empty in Visual Studio 2012. I have Windows 8 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012, Sempron 2.7.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    virtual void test(){
        cout<<"Test"<<endl;
    };
};
class B:public A{
public:
    virtual void test(){
        cout<<"Test2"<<endl;
    };
};
class C:public A{
public:
    virtual void test(){
        cout<<"Test3"<<endl;
    };
};
int main(){
    B a;
    C b;
    int l;
    a.test();
    b.test();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Here is my screenshot]

How to enable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you're running a **release** build, which means the compiler probably just optimized them away.

It's likely that if you look at the generated code, you'll only see some `cout<<`'s, with no objects created.

Change your configuration to **Debug** if you want meaningful debug information.

Comment: Or, as an alternative, disable all optimizations in release build.